# Seeking suggestion - Excel Addin - C# Services

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, add-in

We can currently WCF DataService which has specific interface.  This service basically provides required data based on DataRequest object that is passed to service through.  This service is already used by other .net front ends...

Now I want to expose this service in Excel; so that user can directly gets data through this service. I know i need to develop some sort of addin in excel. What are my options in terms of technology. This adding will be distributed to different business users where they install and include this addin in excel and query they data.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> What are my options in terms of technology?

You have decided to use Excel Addin with C# to consume your WCF service. So that should be fine for development.

To distribute this addin to different users you should be able to use [Click once deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386095.aspx)

Comment: I was expecting in terms of sample; how can I connect to WCF from Excel Add in in VBA...

Comment: Why dont you use Excel Workbook level customisation and then consume WCF service. You will get the advantage of Managed code environment. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163292.aspx

Comment: Kiru I do not want to use VSTO; because for every version of Office you have to have different version of VSTO. I am planning to use C# library COM Add In